# Max length for event resource type in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am building custom input element to create a new event and trying to limit the length as same as the resource type in graph api.

What resource type I am trying to limit is [body/content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itembody?view=graph-rest-1.0)  and [location/displayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/location?view=graph-rest-1.0) while creating an event.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Graph API has only limit for the size of the request which is 3-4MB.

Comment: Can you help me to solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293271/deleting-an-event-returns-success-but-not-worked-actually?noredirect=1#comment118946486_67293271